# Can I save as Model's property as a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to do the following.

I want my model to have a column that store's a hash i.e. name/value pairs.
When I load a record in my model, I don't want it to parse to de-seralize the value from the database UNLESS I access it i.e. lazy initialization.

This is b/c only a few percentage of my rows in the db will have values for the hash, and they will rarely be accessed.

Is this possible?

example usage:

```
user.properties["age"] = 12

user.properties["height"] = xxx

user.save
```

I'm not sure how it would be saved into the db, maybe in json format?

Comment: That is not what [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) means

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can serialize the data.

An excerpt from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

user = User.create(:preferences => { "background" => "black", "display" => large })
User.find(user.id).preferences # => { "background" => "black", "display" => large }
```

Comment: but this property will be de-serialized each time I load the object right? I want it lazy-de-serialized i.e. only if accessed

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveRecord::Base#serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) Does just this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, Hash
end

user = User.create(:preferences => { "background" => "black", "display" => large })
User.find(user.id).preferences # => { "background" => "black", "display" => large }
User.find(user.id).preferences[:background] # => "black"
```

Comment: I stand corrected as I pasted the wrong excerpt, but you should have mentioned that in a comment. After posting just a link, then editing your post with the good excerpt and emphasising my mistake in your answer I can't help of finding the new recent edits that don't get saved process unfair.

Comment: Good point. It would have been more tactful to comment on your almost correct answer. Sorry, It's no excuse, but I'm still new to StackOverflow and learning the ropes. I just want to help out fellow Rubyists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string as a data type, and save it the hash in yaml format. You need to load this yaml string, but IMHO gives you more portability.

```
hash = {a => b, c=>d}
object.properties = hash.to_yaml
.
.
.
hash = Yaml::load(object.properties)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is worthy to add that for proper serialization the `preferences` column should have type of Text, see [Using Rails serialize to save hash to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database)